# Custom WordPress plugin not taking any URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created my own plugin.I have created add user form, show user listing, but when I give EDIT link to user, it's not working. It says page not found.

```
<a href="dashbid-events.php" style="color:blue;">Edit | <a href="#" id="eventdelete_<?php echo $row['id'];?>" onclick="delete_event(this.id)" style="color: blue;">Delete</a>
```

Comment: Your listing is admin panel or any other pages?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

**Reason for 404 Page Not Found**

- Path is not exist anymore or updated
- User doesn't have permission to see that content (Editor and Subscriber)
- custom redirect in function.php

Solution:

- Update Paramlinks (Settings->paramlinks->Select url ->save changes)
- While develop plugin must use constant instead of static path

  `plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/foo-styles.css'`

This `plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )` function gives you full path upto plugin direcoty

**Return URL**

`<host>/wp-content/plugins/example_plugin`

Answer (score 0):

Give full URL to the `dashbid-events.php` file in `href` attribute, instead of a relative path.